# pep381client(pep381run) wont download packages from the official pypi server

Tags: python, repository, local, pypi

I'm setting up a local pypi server for a LAN where there is no internet access. To do so I want to download all the packages from the official pypi server in advance(then I move the server to the LAN).

It looks like the [pep381client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep381client) will do the job. However the command “pep381run.py py-pkgs” just happily prints out “Synchronizing xxx” (xxx is the package name) yet no any packages being found downloaded in the “py-pkgs” directory. Why?

The OS is windows7 BTW.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pep381 client use http, but pypi  can only be used https. This program is not implemented function that redirect url.
I modified the program as this.

file: (YOUR INSALLED DIRECTORY)/pep381client/__init__.py

```
 9: -BASE = 'http://'+pypi
    +BASE = 'https://'+pypi

28: -        _conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(pypi)
    +        _conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(pypi)

37: -        _conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(pypi)
    +        _conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(pypi)
```

Comment: Thank you Yuichiro, that works. So this looks like a bug and I've submit [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/loewis/pep381client/issue/26/pep381run-wont-download-package) to the author.

Comment: Hi Yuichiro, my pep381client broken again. Could you help again ? I posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856803/pep381run-broken-when-restart-httplib-responsenotready)

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone has similar problems, they may be solved by migrating to `bandersnatch`. Which can be found here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bandersnatch

Comment: Be advised that bandersnatch does not support Windows out of the box.