# pep381run broken when restart: httplib.ResponseNotReady

Tags: python, repository, pypi

I'm trying to setup a local pypi server. I use [pep381client](https://bitbucket.org/loewis/pep381client) to synchronize the official PYPI server.

It works fine. But today I encountered a problem:  I stop (by Ctr+C) it and then restart , pep381run raise error as the following:

```
E:\tmp>pep381run.py pypi
Synchronizing OBITools
Copying /packages/source/O/OBITools/OBITools-0.2.000.tar.gz
Copying /packages/source/O/OBITools/OBITools-0.2.002.tar.gz
Copying /packages/source/O/OBITools/OBITools-00.02.503.tar.gz
Copying /packages/source/O/OBITools/OBITools-00.02.500.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\Scripts\pep381run.py", line 31, in <module>
    state.synchronize()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pep381client\__init__.py", line 119, in synchronize
    self._synchronize()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pep381client\__init__.py", line 159, in _synchronize
    self.maybe_copy_file(project, file)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pep381client\__init__.py", line 237, in maybe_copy_file
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1033, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
httplib.ResponseNotReady
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminded by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231543/python-httplib-responsenotready) , after making a dirty and desperate change to the code as the following:

```
def http():
    global _conn
    _conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(pypi) 
    _conn.connect()
    return _conn
```

It works again.